# kerberos multiple tgt requests in eventlog

Tags: windows, security, kerberos, event-log

i'm trying to understand how Kerberos works in Microsoft implementation and what can be deducted from domain event log.

when looking at the documentation it is said that: the first time of day a user logins he requests a tgt, after that for each resource it will ask a service ticket from the tgs.
while examining the logs i see multiple successful tgt request events with id 4768
trying to understand why there are more than one per tgt lifetime?
it looks that some resources cause more tgt requests example:outlook,DC,printers

Comment: Don't know much about the Macrosoft implementation of Kerberos, but... All these requests access the same AD domain? hit the same AD server? with same encryption algorithms? target services use the same Windows version?

Comment: Yes,there is only one domain controller.same realm.same source ..

Comment: What is that TGT *lifetime*, by the way? In the Linux world, by default, a TGT is valid for 10 hours but can be renewed for 7 days, so that many client libs run a thread in the background to automatically renew the TGT every couple of hours.

Comment: Same..10 hours is the default in windows as well